# Infinite wp_mail loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to send mail using wp_mail. I have done the following:

```
add_action ('publish_party', 'party_contact_suppliers');

function party_contact_suppliers($post_id){
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    // get the address cache
    $address_cache = get_option( 'toolset_maps_address_coordinates' );
    $alerts = new WP_Query (array (
        'post_type'    => 'alert',
        'post_status' => 'publish'));
    foreach($alerts as $alert) {
    // find the address within the cache
    foreach ($address_cache as $key => $value) {
         if ( $value['address'] == $alert->center-location ) {
             $lat = $value['lat'];
             $lon = $value['lon'];
             break;
        }
    }

    $to = $alert->post_author;
    wp_mail('myemail@gmail.com','New Party Published', 'Author : '.$to.'     Latitude : '.$lat.'     Longitude : '.$lon);
}
return 0;
}
```

For some reason this has started an infinite loop of mails. There are only 2 alerts in the database.

Can anybody see why this is just looping forever?

Comment: have you check $alerts  with print_r ?

Comment: Also check $address_cache  what you get in that array ?

Comment: $address_cache is a cache of address coordinates that Toolset uses so it doesn't need to ping Google Maps API every time. It will first check the cache to see if it has the address coordinates stored and then if not will check through Google Maps API. So I am pulling the stored coordinates from there.

Comment: The wp_mail is within the $alerts loop though, so I don't think $address_cache is causing the infinite loop.

Comment: I am asking you to check the values what they return ?

Comment: You mean with print_r? I'm not sure I understand how to use that? Where does it output to? How do I see what it is printing?

Comment: I am just telling you to print your array which your getting in these 2 variables and check how many records you are getting.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I get it. I could take this out of the publish_party action, maybe put it into a shortcode, and add that to a page on the website? Something like that?

Comment: Will try that. Thanks dipmala